# Is there a list of all files that affect PATH?

Tags: 14.04, bash, bashrc

There's a path in the $PATH environment variable I'd like to change, though I can't find the script that adds it.

I've looked in `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` but it's not there.

What's a good way of finding who adds a path to my `$PATH`?

Comment: read http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: I've looked through `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`. And `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` do not exist. Where else could this be?

Comment: Thanks A.B - Trying that now. There's just a path I need to update, and it was some script who added it a long time ago

Comment: Which path do you mean, why you're searching for a script?

Comment: You have no change to find the script, which added a path entry to your PATH environment long time ago.

Comment: From the files you listed, what files do *they* source? Hint, check in /etc/profile.d/*.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) has a comprehensive page about environment variables, of which PATH is just one.

The files mentioned there are

#### for the session of one user

- `~/.pam_environment`
- `~/.profile`
- bash only

  - `~/.bashrc`
  - `~/.bash_profile`
  - `~/.bash_login`

#### for all users on the sytem

- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`
- for bash only

  - `/etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: I ended up running grep -r PATH`. Going over the results I found that there wasn't any file that adds the path I was looking to remove! I restarted the machine and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the scripts which change the PATH variable in /etc/profile.d/

```
/home/a>echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
/home/a>ls -l /etc/profile.d/
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 Jan 21  2015 appmenu-qt5.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  663 Nov  6  2014 bash_completion.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  857 Apr 10 19:29 cedilla-brazil.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  301 Feb 20  2013 jdk.csh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  299 Feb 20  2013 jdk.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1940 Dec 16  2014 vte-2.91.sh
/home/a>cat /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh 
export J2SDKDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export J2REDIR=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
/home/a>
```

Refer this [link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Path-6.html#ss6.1) which helped me to find "If bash is used with name sh instead of the name bash, it emulates original Bourne shell initialization: it sources just files **/etc/profile** and ~/.profile and just for login shells."

Comment: Each script and each other thing can change your PATH environment.